# Conway's Game of Life in C++ with a Board Struct

Tags: c++, beginner, simulation, game-of-life

I made the game of Life in C++ for a highschool class project. The website we're using doesn't have an autograder for C++, and my programming teacher doesn't really know how to program... so I'd love some external feedback! While I believe this simulation works, I'm not sure about the quality of the code. I tried making it as readable and fluid as possible, but I'm new to C++. Let me know how "C++" this code is, and about any pitfalls I may have dug myself into.

I'm unsure what version of C++ this website uses, but I believe its pre-C++11? (Due to a lack of smart pointers.)

I highly reccomend running it on the website here: https://codehs.com/sandbox/drakepickett/game-of-life

p.s. - I added console clearing and such just as a cheeky experiment to make it look nice. Not sure how safe console clearing with  my method is :)

Thank you very much!

Here is the raw code:

```
#include "util.h"
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

struct Board
{
    int BOARD_SIZE;
    char liveCell;
    char deadCell;
    vector<vector<char> > cells;
    
    void populateBoard()
    {
        int numLive = readInt(1, BOARD_SIZE*BOARD_SIZE, "Please enter number of active cells between 1 and " + to_string(BOARD_SIZE*BOARD_SIZE)+ ": ");
        for (int i = 0; i < numLive; i++)
        {
            int x, y;
            while (true)
            {
                x = randInt(0, this->BOARD_SIZE-1);
                y = randInt(0, this->BOARD_SIZE-1);
                if (this->cells[x][y] == this->deadCell) break;
            }
            
            this->cells[x][y] = this->liveCell;
        }
    }
    
    Board(int size, char liveCell, char deadCell)
    {
        this->BOARD_SIZE = size;
        this->liveCell = liveCell;
        this->deadCell = deadCell;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < this->BOARD_SIZE; i++)
        {
            vector<char> row;
            for (int j = 0; j < this->BOARD_SIZE; j++)
            {
                row.push_back(this->deadCell);
            }
            this->cells.push_back(row);
        }
        
        populateBoard();
    }
    
    int getNumNeighbors(int row, int column)
    {
        int numNeighbors = 0;
        
        vector<int> xRange;
        vector<int> yRange;
        
        if (row > 0) yRange.push_back(-1);
        yRange.push_back(0);
        if (row < this->cells.size()-1) yRange.push_back(1);
        
        if (column > 0) xRange.push_back(-1);
        xRange.push_back(0);
        if (column < this->cells.size()-1) xRange.push_back(1);
        
        for (int y : yRange)
        {
            for (int x : xRange)
            {
                if (x == 0 && y == 0) continue;
                //cout <<"Y: " << row << " | Row: " << row+y << " _ X: " << column << " | Column: " << column + x << endl;
                if (this->cells[row+y][column+x] == this->liveCell) numNeighbors++;
                //cout << "We made it!" << endl;
            }
        }
        
        return numNeighbors;
    }
    
    void update()
    {
        vector<vector<char> > b = this->cells;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < this->BOARD_SIZE; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < this->BOARD_SIZE; j++)
            {
                int numNeighbors = getNumNeighbors(i, j);
                
                if (this->cells[i][j] == this->liveCell && !(numNeighbors == 2 || numNeighbors == 3)) b[i][j] = this-> deadCell;
                if (this->cells[i][j] == this->deadCell && numNeighbors == 3) b[i][j] = this->liveCell;
                
            }
        }
        
        this->cells = b;
    }
    
    void print()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < this->BOARD_SIZE; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < this->BOARD_SIZE; j++)
            {
                cout << this->cells[i][j] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
};


void cls()
{
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    this_thread::sleep_for(1000ms);
    std::cout << "\x1B[2J\x1B[H";
}

int main()
{
    Board board(15, 'X', '-');
    int numIterations = readInt(0, 1000, "Run how many iterations? (0-1000): ");
    for (int i = 0; i < numIterations; i++)
    {
        cls();
        cout << "Iteration " << i << endl;
        board.print();
        board.update();
    }
    cls();
    cout <<"Final Board" << endl;
    board.print();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A possible trick is to surround the map by extra cases. That might avoid bound checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It is a good idea to list headers in alphabetical order, this enables searching for the reader. Also user-defined headers can be separated from global ones.

2.BOARD_SIZE, dead and alive can be consts. As these are not changed once the object is initialized.

3. Loops to initialize are not required. You can write like:

   vector<vector> (BOARD_SIZE,vector(BOARD_SIZE,DEAD));
4. Also,the boolean logic of determining the fate of each cell can be enclosed in a function.

   bool shouldDie(int row,int col) {
   return (this->cells[row][col] == this->liveCell && !(numNeighbors == 2 || numNeighbors == 3));
   }